# App keeps stopping in android studio, i am making an mandir app

Tags: java, android

I am making an app in which two buttons are there, both change the resource of one image. The app keeps stopping, I dont know why.

I gues it is because of the api level as the api level is the lowest.

Here goes my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button lightUp = findViewById(R.id.light);
    Button unLight = findViewById(R.id.unlight);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lightUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.diya);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lit_diya);
            }
        });

        unLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.diya);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_lit_diya);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here goes the activity_main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mandir"
        android:layout_width="508dp"
        android:layout_height="521dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.473"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/mandir" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/unlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unlight Diya"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mandir" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lit Up Diya"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.82"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mandir" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/diya"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/not_lit_diya" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is my logcat error, i dont understand this error but if you can, please tell me the meaning and the solutions.

```
2021-02-04 20:04:00.791 30922-30922/com.example.digitalmandir E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.digitalmandir, PID: 30922
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.digitalmandir/com.example.digitalmandir.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:169)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:684)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
        at com.example.digitalmandir.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:13)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

There is one more error which one is ate the top

```
2021-02-04 20:04:00.046 30922-30922/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
```

Comment: put the initialisation of the buttons inside onCreate

Comment: Can you please explain it briefly? C'z I am new In Java

Comment: put these lines Button lightUp = findViewById(R.id.light); Button unLight = findViewById(R.id.unlight); inside the onCreate method, just below setContentView

Comment: Thanks Walid, that helped me out ! ;)
Well, I am just a 12 year Old :)

Comment: No problem, keep learning :)

Comment: @ParvanshuSharma Wow, Seems like Real White Hat Jr. Keep it up.

Comment: Actually a few weeks ago only my father subscribed White Hat Jr., Thanks!, Hello there, I also need to add a gif n my code, please can you help me out again : )

Comment: You can help at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065263/add-a-gif-in-android-studio-java