# Add a GIF in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

I need to add a GIF in my code snippet on the screen, i need it to be played continuously
and without stopping I saw many blogs, QnAs on google but I didn't find the answer, here goes my MainActivity.java(Showing MainActivity.class as it was not allowing me to post the whole code) -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView lightUp = findViewById(R.id.lightUp4);
        Button unLight = findViewById(R.id.unlight);
        ImageView AgarbattiBtn = findViewById(R.id.agarbattiBtn);
        MediaPlayer Sound_matchstick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.matchstick);
        MediaPlayer Om_Bhur = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.om_bhur);

        lightUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView image1 = findViewById(R.id.diya);
                image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lit_diya);
                lightUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Sound_matchstick.start();
                if(lightUp.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && AgarbattiBtn.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    Om_Bhur.start();
                }
            }
        });

        unLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView image2 = findViewById(R.id.diya);
                image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_lit_diya);
                AgarbattiBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.agrabatti).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                lightUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Om_Bhur.stop();
            }
        });

        AgarbattiBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AgarbattiBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.agrabatti).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(lightUp.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && AgarbattiBtn.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    Om_Bhur.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mandir"
        android:layout_width="508dp"
        android:layout_height="521dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.473"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/mandir" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/unlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/diya"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mandir"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/not_lit_diya" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lightUp4"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unlight"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/matchstick" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.24"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/krishna_ji" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.76"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mata_rani" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/agarbattiBtn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.86"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/agarbatti" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/agrabatti"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.59000003"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/agarbatti" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3rd party view library like [this](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) because custom solutions are too complicated to write from what I've seen.

Just import it into you project

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
}
```

And use:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/src_anim"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_anim"
    />
```

> If drawables declared by android:src and/or android:background are GIF
> files then they will be automatically recognized as GifDrawables and
> animated.

There are methods for GIF control such as:

- **stop()** - stops the animation, can be called from any thread
- **start()** -    starts the animation, can be called from any thread
- isRunning() -    returns whether animation is currently running or
  not reset() -    rewinds the animation, does not restart stopped one
- setSpeed(float    factor) - sets new animation speed factor, eg.
  passing 2.0f will double the animation speed seekTo(int position)
  seeks animation   (within current loop) to given position (in milliseconds)
- getDuration() - returns duration of one loop of the animation
- getCurrentPosition() - returns elapsed time from the beginning of a
  current loop of animation

Please refer to the [docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/pl.droidsonroids.gif/android-gif-drawable/1.2.16/index.html) for more info :)

Comment: Thanks, it "would" help me as I am not able to do that now, can you please explain me that where can I add these lines please? ;-)

Comment: No problem, I ijust now opened the link https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable which you gave and I got that how do I should do it, I have marked your answer correct!

Comment: .start() is not working, it is showing Cannot resolve method 'start' in 'GifImageView'

Comment: Hold ctrl and click on the class name ex. GifImageView to see source file of that library and see which methods and objects it has to figure out how to use it in addition to documentation.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I tried, Now I just saw that I do not need to use .play() as the gif is playing already and I am not able to figure the objects out. Thanks :-)